# Route to different actions with the same url with different params

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I'm building api with such routes:
`/items` and `/items/{id}`.
For now I want to route this routes to two different actions. I am not able to configure it with attributes, here is config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "route1", 
    "/items", 
    new { controller = "Items", action = "Get" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "route2", 
    "/items/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Items", action = "Get" });
```

But this route just doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Change the second action to be called `GetByID` and rename it in the route to match.

Comment: Thanks for an idea. This is the easiest solution. Do you know any other approaches?

Comment: Why are you not able to configure it with attributes?

Comment: FWIW, what you have should work fine, except both routes are being taken to the same action, which is what you said you explicitly did not want. What is the actual issue?

Comment: @IvanRubanau show an example of the two different actions you are trying to map to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have 2 action methods with the same name and map them using route templating unless those methods are mapped to different HTTP method (all this due to how model binding is working):

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Edit(int id) { ... }

   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Edit(int id, Product product) { ... }
}
```

But yes, this is possible to do using attribute routing. If you cannot use this approach, then you have only the following options:

- rename one of the action's name;
- combine both actions into one with optional `id` parameter.

```
    public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Get(int? id) 
        { 
            if (id.HasValue())
            { // logic as in second action }
            else
            { // first action logic }
        }
    }
```

and define routing as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "route",
    template: "{controller=Items}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
```